# MongoDB cannot start server: The default storage engine 'wiredTiger' is not available with this build of mongod

Tags: mongodb

MongoDB server failing to start with the following error:

> 2015-12-13T00:49:12.191+0600 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
>   2015-12-13T00:49:12.195+0600 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in
>
> initAndListen: 28663 Cannot start server. The default storage engine
>   'wiredTiger' is not available with this build of mongod. Please
>   specify a different storage engine explicitly, e.g.
>   --storageEngine=mmapv1., terminating
>         2015-12-13T00:49:12.195+0600 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 100

Answer (score 130):

Well... There appears to be a version conflict: you are probably running a 32bit version of Mongo. Just do as they say and actually use the other default storage engine:

Write the command as follows in your Mongo/bin directory:

```
mongod --storageEngine=mmapv1 --dbpath [your-path]
```

Should solve the problem. I guess you don't quite mind about using the good old mmapv1 instead of wiredTiger do you?

Comment: I tried mongod.exe --storageEngine=mmapv1 and it worked

Comment: wow great , works fine with win10 32 bit, it even run in my browser smooth (chrome 127.0.0.1:27017 )

Answer (score 18):

Look carefully error, an error message is very clear that the causes and solutions for the problems, as long as we later in the installation MonogoDB command to add a parameter --storageEngine = mmapv1, will wiredTiger engine switched mmapv1 engine, you can successfully install.

So your complete command will be as follows:

> mongod --dbpath MongoDb_Location_In_Your_HDD\data --storageEngine=mmapv1

Note: MongoDb_Location_In_Your_HDD means the location where you put your MongoDb e.g.- D:\mongodb

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: i didnt notice that "tiger" word written. I wonder why they dont make it as a default one ? @Mojam Dewan?

Answer (score 12):

I also come across this issues when i installed mongodb 32 bit msi for windows server.

Reason could be:

I think for mongodb 32 bit the database engine wont take automatically we need to explicitly give them while configuring the db path

The fix is below:

Run command prompt as administrator

d:\mongodb>mongod --dbpath "data" **--storageEngine "mmapv1"**

After adding the above bold code the issue resolved.

Thanks
Dev

Answer (score 6):

You can use mongod --storageEngine=mmapv1 --dbpath "Your Path"

**For me :**

> "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin\mongod.exe"
>   --storageEngine=mmapv1  --dbpath="C:\data\db"

Hope it works fine for you too.

Comment: mongod --dbpath="C:\data\db" --storageEngine=mmapv1

Answer (score 3):

Because you are using the MongoDB on a 32bit machine, the storage engine wiredTiger is not supported on 32bit machine. There are two solutions of this problem:

1. upgrade your system to 64bit
2. change your storage engine to the engines that are suitable for 32bit system,like mmapv1, and run mongod again.

The result is like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you use 32 bit Windows system, then execute the following in the command prompt:-

```
1. Go to the bin directory of MongoDB using the command
```

> cd C:\ProgramFile\MongoDB\Server\3.x\bin

```
2. Type the following command
```

> mongod.exe --storageEngine=mmapv1

and click Enter. It will solve the error. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I created a directory in C drive -

```
C:\data\db
```

and ran the command as below, it worked for me.

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\mongodb-win32-i386-3.2.22\bin>mongod.exe --storageEngine=mmapv1
```

Answer (score 0):

I was on MongoDB v4, using a mongod binary from MongoDB v3.6 worked for me, none of the other solutions worked.