# Not able to run mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have installed mongodb, and also created data/db folders. However when i run "mongod" command on my cmd it does not run the mongodb and throws some error. What is the possible solution of this problem? here is the screenshot of the error:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5AgN.png)

Comment: The error message appears to tell you exactly what to do as a solution. Have you tried that? Also, next time, include the text of the error itself, not a screenshot.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34243731/mongodb-28663-cannot-start-server

Comment: Try running mongod like this - `mongod --storageEngine=mmapv1`

.You probably have a 32bit system and wiredTiger Storage Engine is only supported by a 64 bit system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use mmapv1 engine instead of wired tiger as suggested in the error. for e.g mongod.exe --storageEngine=mmapv1