# MongoDB "The default storage engine 'wiredTiger' is not available with this build of mongod " + " ..no /data/db folder.."

Tags: windows, mongodb

After first installing MongoDb and running the `mongod` command 
in the `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin>` directory, I get the error:

> "The default storage engine 'wiredTiger' is not available with this build of mongod"

And then a second error

> " ..no /data/db folder..".

Running windows 10 32-bit.

EDIT: I had two different problems, (as the question title says) I combined them to solve my problem. I hope this will serve as a reference to other newbies if they are in the same boat. So thanks for the down votes, people :)

Comment: [WiredTiger doesn't work on 32 bit](http://serverfault.com/questions/742230/mongo-db-installation-showing-storage-engine-error). First Google hit. Read [ask] and try searching first.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB cannot start server: The default storage engine 'wiredTiger' is not available with this build of mongod](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34243731/mongodb-cannot-start-server-the-default-storage-engine-wiredtiger-is-not-avai)

Answer (score 4):

I did the following:

1. Ran Node.js command prompt as Administrator
2. Made a C:\data\db directory
3. Ran "cd C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin" command
4. Executed "mongod --storageEngine=mmapv1 --dbpath C:\data\db"

i.e, looked like the following :

*** C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin> mongod --storageEngine=mmapv1 --dbpath C:\data\db

---

PS: Sorry people, but the reason for answering my own question is that I hope this will help someone else if they ever are in my position.

Please refer to this question's answers(I borrowed from there) :

[MongoDB cannot start server: The default storage engine 'wiredTiger' is not available with this build of mongod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34243731/mongodb-cannot-start-server-the-default-storage-engine-wiredtiger-is-not-avai)

Comment: Don't copy-paste answers from proposed duplicates, accept the duplicate instead. :)

Comment: You mean " Welcome to the merciless world of hardcore programmers"? meh!  PS: Thanks, will try to keep that in mind :)

Comment: Look, I'm happy that you were able to solve two different problems by yourself and wanted to share your progress; the problem is that both problems separately have been asked and answered before already. There's nothing against you personally. :)

Comment: Yeah, I understand repetitive questions are almost like spam emails - I hate them myself, as well.  Got a bit carried away by 'newbie enthusiasm', but Nothing taken personally :) :)

Answer (score 0):

Just execute this command in your Mongo/bin directory:

```
mongod --storageEngine=mmapv1 --dbpath [your-path]
```

Answer (score 0):

In terms of " ..no /data/db folder..". error you have to create this directory manually on C:\ so the path of the directory is C:\data\db