# Error while setting up MongoDB on windowsXP 32-bit?

Tags: mongodb

I have downloaded MongoDB 32-bit version and I have successfully completed the installation.

I have made 2 folders:
1) `data` inside it `db` folder
2) `log` folder

when I navigate to `bin` folder and try to run `mongod` it gives error.([see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6jnv.png))

Comment: Look at error carefully. It suggest you the possible solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB cannot start server: The default storage engine 'wiredTiger' is not available with this build of mongod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34243731/mongodb-cannot-start-server-the-default-storage-engine-wiredtiger-is-not-avai)

Comment: @sushant I tried to use this command `mongod --directoryperdb --storageEngine=mmapv1 --dbpath C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\data\db --logpath C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\log` but still getting error.

Comment: @SushantPimple I am getting error see I have edited my question

Comment: @SushantPimple https://imgur.com/a/JgtFk

Comment: Images are useful in a post, but **make sure the post is still clear without them**. Instead of linking to a screenshot of your error, copy and paste or type the actual data into the post directly.
cf http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: @VinceBowdren Thank you I will keep that in mind :)

Comment: @stonerock Remember you can [edit] this question, to improve it. On this site, editing and improvement is encouraged from everybody; it's the way we collaborate to make better questions and answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35222910/2107318)

Just run command with following options only

> mongod --dbpath MongoDB_Location\data --storageEngine=mmapv1

Note: MongoDB_Location means the location where you put your MongoDB 
e.g.: D:\mongodb

Edit : Put --dbpath in double quotes as your path contains spaces.

This [article](https://blog.ajduke.in/2013/04/10/install-setup-and-start-mongodb-on-windows/) will help you in steps to install MongoDB on Windows.

Comment: @stonerock Replace MongoDB_Location with C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2

Comment: should it be `MongoDB_Location\data\db` as I have made `db` folder inside data folder.