# Mongo Shell can't working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

[image]**MongoDB shell version v3.6.4
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
MongoDB server version: 3.6.4
Server has startup warnings:
2018-05-11T07:47:29.885+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten]**

This kind of error a generate when I want to start mongo in terminal of AWS

Comment: can't work? server is or starting or what?

Comment: a server is working properly but mongo shell can't respond that in a screenshot

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34243731/mongodb-cannot-start-server-the-default-storage-engine-wiredtiger-is-not-avai?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa maybe the same?