# mongodb issue : please define different storage engine explicitly

Tags: mongodb

I have windows 8.1 with 32 bit and i am installing mongodb 3.2.
I already try this command 
[MongoDB cannot start server: The default storage engine 'wiredTiger' is not available with this build of mongod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34243731/mongodb-cannot-start-server-the-default-storage-engine-wiredtiger-is-not-avai)
here **[your-path]** mean that data folder path to store data right..?
please check image for full explanation...
Error: [mongodb error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hswGj.png)

Comment: Attach image is self explained, use different storage engine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution of this question is run below command

```
mongod.exe --storageEngine=mmapv1
```

and then open another command window and then type the following at the command prompt to start the mongo REPL shell:

```
mongo
```

then it pinging to 127.0.0.1